# SQL get record with highest amount in given hour

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get a record with highest `amount` in given hour.

Data in DB:

```
id | date                | amount 
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
1  | 2014-07-11 18:10:00 | 10
2  | 2014-07-11 18:20:00 | 20
3  | 2014-07-11 18:30:00 | 100
4  | 2014-07-11 18:40:00 | 10
5  | 2014-07-11 19:10:00 | 50
6  | 2014-07-11 19:20:00 | 60
```

Desired outcome:

```
id | date                | amount 
---------------------------------
3  | 2014-07-11 18:30:00 | 100
6  | 2014-07-11 19:20:00 | 60
```

Comment: What did you try? And what is the datatype for the date column?

Comment: The date column is datetime datatype.

Comment: Why do you need the ID returned back? It's a pretty trivial problem without the ID, but you need to explain the business rules in order to understand what you should do when there are tied amounts in the same period and you are expected to return an ID. sgeddes' query works if you want them both to each return a row (same hour listed more than once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can join the table back to itself using the max aggregate, grouping by the hour and date:

```
select d.*
from data d
  join (select max(amount) maxamount, hour(date) datehour, date(date) date
        from data
        group by hour(date), date(date)
        ) d2 on d.amount = d2.maxamount 
          and hour(d.date) = d2.datehour
          and date(d.date) = d2.date
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df2bc/3)

Comment: nice query :) seems like it would be slow though when you have a large table because of the multiple join conditions

Comment: This is an interesting one the OP gave us. I just tried your query and got 'cannot reopen table d'.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I created a temporary table and thus it is against the rules to refer to it >1.

Answer (score 2):

something like this? -- assuming table name is transactions

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        id, date, amount
    FROM transactions
    ORDER BY amount DESC
) AS t
GROUP BY HOUR(date) , DATE(date);
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81d52/1)

Comment: Won't that give you an error for not grouping by ID?

Comment: But your result still does not resemble OPs Desired Outcome. It only finds the amount -- not the id, and it does not indicate which hour that amount was for.

Comment: @MJB you can group by anything.. you don't need to group by id only.. generally its a good practice to group by id unless you need to manipulate the data in a specific manner

Comment: +1 Why is this answer downvoted? Check the fiddle dammit. This is a good solution and it does answer the OP's question. Do you guys even read the answers before downvoting? **This is a good working solution.**

Comment: Not sure why im gettin a downvote either as this orders it from greatest to lowest then gets the first one.. but whatever

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny tbh this is probably the best way to do it since its pulling from the table only once too :)

Comment: It probably got downvoted because there is no guarantee that the maximum amount will be returned by this query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.`

Answer (score 2):

You can also approach this with the `not exists` approach:

```
select d.*
from data d
where not exists (select 1
                  from data d2
                  where date(d2.date) = date(d.date) and
                        hour(d2.date) = hour(d.date) and
                        d2.amount > d.amount
                 );
```

This is just an alternative solution.  Sometimes `not exists` is faster than the `group by` with `join`, but probably not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice:

```
SELECT      Id, 
            Dating,
            Amount
FROM        Tab
WHERE       Amount IN (SELECT       MAX(Amount) AS 'Maximum Amount'
                       FROM         Tab
                       GROUP BY     HOUR(Dating), DATE(Dating))
```

You can see that here->  [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/672c6f/15)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks for pointing that out. My bad!! I have edited my answer. This one does show the right ID's. Check out the fiddle.

Comment: There will be another issue with this just as a fyi.. when you are looking over multiple days the data will still be grouped by the hour number so you need to add `GROUP BY HOUR(dating), DATE(dating)`

Comment: @JohnRuddell Good catch. So often we just ignore even looking at the ID field in such a query. Nice reminder!!

Comment: this doesn't work when a non-maximum amount in one hour matches the maximum amount in another hour see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/458f4/1